# Troubles with parsing ISO8601 time in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

I'm trying to convert this string "2011-11-23T17:59:00Z" to an NSDate.

I've seen many people have this problem, but everyone has a slightly different format.  I haven't been able to hack a solution.

I've tried code such as:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormat.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterFullStyle;
[dateFormat setDateFormat: @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"];
NSString* date = ""2011-11-23T17:59:00Z"";
NSString *dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate: date];
```

dateString always comes back NULL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NSDateFormatter stringFromDate takes an NSDate object and you're passing it a string.
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Try NSDateFormatter dateFromString.

If you use dateFromString:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat: @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"];
NSString* dateStr = @"2011-11-23T17:59:00Z";
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateStr];

NSLog(@"date: %@", date);
```

Outputs:

```
2011-12-14 00:34:57.587 Craplet[440:707] date: 2011-11-23 22:59:00 +0000
```

Comment: This answer is incorrect. The format string should not quote the `Z`.